# Specman On the Fly Generation: How to constrain a list whose values are differ from each other at least 2

Tags: specman

I need to generate a random list values with the next constrain:

```
my_list[i] not in [my_list[i-1] .. my_list[i-1] + 1]
```

i.e. all values in the list are different and with at least difference of 2 between each other. All code variations I've tried failed, e.g.:

```
   var prev_val : uint = 0;
   gen my_list keeping {
       it.size() == LIST_SIZE;
       it.all_different(it);

       for each (val) in it {
                val not in [prev_val .. prev_val + 1];
                prev_val = val;
        };
    };
```

How such list can be generated? Thank you for your help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am not sure I fully understand the request but following your code:

```
gen my_list keeping {
    it.size() == LIST_SIZE;
    it.all_different(it);
    keep for each (val) in it {
        val != prev;
        val != prev + 1;
    };
};
```

This will generate a list (all items will be generate together) according to your rule:

```
my_list[i] not in [my_list[i-1] .. my_list[i-1] + 1]
```

But the following list is a valid solution:  0,2,1,3,5,4,6,8,7,9,11,10,12,...
which doesn't follow "the all values in the list are different and with at least difference of 2 between each other".

To generate a list according to the "text request", you must use double keep for each and abs:

```
gen my_list keeping {
    it.size() == LIST_SIZE;
    for each (val1) using index (i1) in it {
        for each (val2) using index (i2) in it {
            i1 < i2 => abs(val1-val2) >= 2;
    };
};
```

If you want my_list to be sorted (and will be solved faster) :

```
gen my_list keeping {
    it.size() == LIST_SIZE;
    it.size() == LIST_SIZE;
    it.all_different(it);
    for each (val) in it {
        val >= prev + 2;
    };
};
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try the following:

```
gen my_list keeping {
  it.size() == 10;
  it.all_different(it);

  for each (val) in it {
    index > 0 => 
       val not in [value(it[index - 1]) .. value(it[index - 1]) + 1];
  };
};
```

The solver requires the `it[index - 1]` expression in the constraint be "fixed" at the point of generation, hence the use of `value(...)`. This means that the list will be generated element by element.

If that's a problem, you could change to:

```
    index > 0 => 
       val != it[index - 1] + 1;
```

This should be equivalent, since the `all_different(...)` constraint should make sure that an element doesn't have the same value as the previous one. Naturally, this won't work if you have a wider set.

Comment: Unfortunately  your first solution will create an ICFS and this isn't recommended.
(all_different require the items to be solved together while the value/read_only defines order).